# ReactJS - Method not allowed in JMeter but in web browser works

Tags: reactjs, spring, rest, jmeter, http-status-code-405

I'm getting error 405 while trying to upload files from client side in JMeter. I've also tried recording scripts but that doesn't seem to work because it doesn't capture needed action. Everything works fine when done in the web browser and I don't get then any errors, but when it comes to testing in JMeter the error appears.
[image]

I have an application written in ReactJS and SpringBoot.

Comment: Take a look https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

Comment: Can you show the method you are using, image from jmeter METHOD session from request? 405 is a method not allowed, maybe you are trying to put a POST in a route that only accepts GET. or something like that. Can you share the server side code from route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your server response you're allowed to only send [GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) and [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) methods while file upload is possible with [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) and [PUT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT) so most probably you either need to ensure that your URL is correct or it might be the case you need to be authenticated prior to uploading the file and this authentication logic fails somewhere somehow.

If you properly configure JMeter and the web browser for recording, to wit:

1. [Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
2. [Install JMeter's certificate into your browser](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
3. [Copy the file(s) you are going to upload to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/)
4. [Configure your browser to use JMeter as the proxy](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-set-proxy-server-all-major-internet-browsers-windows/)

you should be able to record your browser's HTTP and HTTPS traffic and JMeter should generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler(s) and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)(s) so you should be able to replay your script (some correlation may be still [required](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start))